# ionic 3 app has stopped after add one signal notification plugin

Tags: angular, cordova, gradle, ionic3

I am try to use one signal push notification plugin with my ionic 3 application application  run correct without one signal plugin but when install one signal native plugin and run android on my device application not run and alert by this massage application has stopped !!

i am sure install google play service on sdk manger.
WARNING: The onesignal-gradle-plugin MUST be before com.android.application!

this warning push when run android and when open build.gradle iam show that apply plugin: 'com.android.application' but i dont have apply plugin to one signal ,however i am install plugin !!

ionic info:

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.0
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.0.1
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.0.1
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.8.0
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 25.2.5
Node              : v6.16.0
npm               : 4.6.1
OS                : Windows 10
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : C:\Users\Muhammed Hassan Ali\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```